# c# writing to spreadsheet using XmlWriter

Tags: c#

I'm using an `XmlWriter` to create a spreadsheet and have been successful with the basic setup. The documentation is available here [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx#odc_xmlss_span)

and I'm trying to use some advanced features like making a cell span several columns, change font color, cell color, etc. I can see the xml tags needed for this but I dont know how to convert this to the format that `XmlWriter` required. Can someone help me out a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XmlWriter` is a serial way to write XML, I mean you write as if you were hand writing it.

So, if you can generate the XML, simply follow the steps that you require in order to use the XmlWriter.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use a library like NPOI ?

http://npoi.codeplex.com/

Comment: Why bloat a software with a library, if you're just trying to write a few bytes that take 5 min perusing the documentation?

Comment: yes but NPOI has merged cell and font built in. In my opinion more easy to write advanced excel files.

Comment: Bloat a software with a library? Libraries are so you don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Dave, I agree that libraries are useful when you need a big part of a funcionality that you don't need to create yourself, however, you need to weight in the pro and cons of using a full blown library when a few lines of code would sufice. Remember that you don't need a cannon to kill a fly.

Comment: Depends on the weight of the cannon. If it's (for all practical purposes) weightless and sizeless, I wouldn't mind.